# C++ create process command line executing powershell command in command line arguments

Tags: c++

I want to create process with something like this:

```
LPTSTR cmdArgs = _T("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe PowerShell -Command Add-AppxPackage -Path \"C:\\Users\\TEST2\\abc.appx\" ");
```

call the API as below:

```
CreateProcess(NULL, cmdArgs, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)
```

Here when I do so, application is goin into deadlock.

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear at all.

Comment: why not this ? : CreateProcess(NULL,
    "PowerShell -Command Add-AppxPackage -Path \"C:\\Users\\TEST2\\abc.appx\"", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi)